# Create a CSV to save the result of web-scraping

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, css-selectors

I'm scraping information from some links indicated in the code below.

I'd like to save all the data in a unique CSV file.

I think there is a problem with my code, in fact when I print the detail_flights (or I try to insert them in a CSV file) I obtain only the result of the last link scraped.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pprint

list_link = ['https://www.kayak.it/flights/MIL-BCN/2021-09-05/2021-09-06/?sort=bestflight__a&fs=stops=0', 'https://www.kayak.it/flights/MIL-PAR/2021-09-05/2021-09-06/?sort=bestflight__a&fs=stops=0', 'https://www.kayak.it/flights/MIL-ROM/2021-09-05/2021-09-06/?sort=bestflight__a&fs=stops=0']

wd = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',chrome_options = chrome_options)
wd.maximize_window()
wd.implicitly_wait(50)
#driver.get("https://account.battle.net/creation/flow/creation-full")
wait = WebDriverWait(wd, 20)

detail_flights = []

for link in list_link:
  wd.get(link)
  try:
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[title='Accetta']"))).click()
  except:
    pass

  try:
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[id='onetrust-accept-btn-handler']"))).click()
  except:
    pass

  
j = 0
lngth = len(wd.find_elements_by_css_selector(".mainInfo"))
for i in range(lngth):
    try:
        if len(wd.find_elements_by_css_selector(".mainInfo")) > 0:
            elements = wd.find_elements_by_css_selector(".mainInfo")
            wd.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", elements[j])
            #print(elements[j].get_attribute('innerText'))
            j = j + 1

            date = link.replace('https://www.kayak.it/flights/', '')
            data_partenza = date[8:18]
            data_ritorno = date[19:29]
            
            detail_flights.append({elements[j].get_attribute('innerText'), data_partenza, data_ritorno})

            print(detail_flights)
        else:
            print('Nothing more to scrape')
    except:
        pass
```

This is the output - I'd like to obtain only the last row of the output and not all the repeated rows. And I'd like to obtain a row for each link scraped.

```
 [{'13:10 – 20:03\nMIL Centrale\n‐\nROM Termini\n0 cambi\n6h 53m\n13:57 – 20:40\nROM Termini\n‐\nMIL Centrale\n0 cambi\n6h 43m', '2021-09-05', '2021-09-06'}]
    [{'13:10 – 20:03\nMIL Centrale\n‐\nROM Termini\n0 cambi\n6h 53m\n13:57 – 20:40\nROM Termini\n‐\nMIL Centrale\n0 cambi\n6h 43m', '2021-09-05', '2021-09-06'}, {'9:30 – 10:40\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n15:00 – 16:10\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m', '2021-09-05', '2021-09-06'}]
    [{'13:10 – 20:03\nMIL Centrale\n‐\nROM Termini\n0 cambi\n6h 53m\n13:57 – 20:40\nROM Termini\n‐\nMIL Centrale\n0 cambi\n6h 43m', '2021-09-05', '2021-09-06'}, {'9:30 – 10:40\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n15:00 – 16:10\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m', '2021-09-05', '2021-09-06'}, {'15:00 – 16:10\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n13:40 – 14:50\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m', '2021-09-05', '2021-09-06'}]
    [{'13:10 – 20:03\nMIL Centrale\n‐\nROM Termini\n0 cambi\n6h 53m\n13:57 – 20:40\nROM Termini\n‐\nMIL Centrale\n0 cambi\n6h 43m', '2021-09-05', '2021-09-06'}, {'9:30 – 10:40\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n15:00 – 16:10\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m', '2021-09-05', '2021-09-06'}, {'15:00 – 16:10\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n13:40 – 14:50\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m', '2021-09-05', '2021-09-06'}, {'2021-09-06', '2021-09-05', '15:00 – 16:10\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n11:00 – 12:10\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m'}]
    [{'13:10 – 20:03\nMIL Centrale\n‐\nROM Termini\n0 cambi\n6h 53m\n13:57 – 20:40\nROM Termini\n‐\nMIL Centrale\n0 cambi\n6h 43m', '2021-09-05', '2021-09-06'}, {'9:30 – 10:40\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n15:00 – 16:10\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m', '2021-09-05', '2021-09-06'}, {'15:00 – 16:10\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n13:40 – 14:50\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m', '2021-09-05', '2021-09-06'}, {'2021-09-06', '2021-09-05', '15:00 – 16:10\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n11:00 – 12:10\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m'}, {'2021-09-06', '2021-09-05', '19:30 – 20:40\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n15:00 – 16:10\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m'}]
    [{'13:10 – 20:03\nMIL Centrale\n‐\nROM Termini\n0 cambi\n6h 53m\n13:57 – 20:40\nROM Termini\n‐\nMIL Centrale\n0 cambi\n6h 43m', '2021-09-05', '2021-09-06'}, {'9:30 – 10:40\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n15:00 – 16:10\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m', '2021-09-05', '2021-09-06'}, {'15:00 – 16:10\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n13:40 – 14:50\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m', '2021-09-05', '2021-09-06'}, {'2021-09-06', '2021-09-05', '15:00 – 16:10\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n11:00 – 12:10\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m'}, {'2021-09-06', '2021-09-05', '19:30 – 20:40\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n15:00 – 16:10\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m'}, {'9:30 – 10:40\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n11:00 – 12:10\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m', '2021-09-05', '2021-09-06'}]
    [{'13:10 – 20:03\nMIL Centrale\n‐\nROM Termini\n0 cambi\n6h 53m\n13:57 – 20:40\nROM Termini\n‐\nMIL Centrale\n0 cambi\n6h 43m', '2021-09-05', '2021-09-06'}, {'9:30 – 10:40\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n15:00 – 16:10\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m', '2021-09-05', '2021-09-06'}, {'15:00 – 16:10\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n13:40 – 14:50\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m', '2021-09-05', '2021-09-06'}, {'2021-09-06', '2021-09-05', '15:00 – 16:10\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n11:00 – 12:10\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m'}, {'2021-09-06', '2021-09-05', '19:30 – 20:40\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n15:00 – 16:10\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m'}, {'9:30 – 10:40\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n11:00 – 12:10\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m', '2021-09-05', '2021-09-06'}, {'19:30 – 20:40\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n22:00 – 23:10\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m', '2021-09-05', '2021-09-06'}]
    [{'13:10 – 20:03\nMIL Centrale\n‐\nROM Termini\n0 cambi\n6h 53m\n13:57 – 20:40\nROM Termini\n‐\nMIL Centrale\n0 cambi\n6h 43m', '2021-09-05', '2021-09-06'}, {'9:30 – 10:40\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n15:00 – 16:10\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m', '2021-09-05', '2021-09-06'}, {'15:00 – 16:10\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n13:40 – 14:50\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m', '2021-09-05', '2021-09-06'}, {'2021-09-06', '2021-09-05', '15:00 – 16:10\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n11:00 – 12:10\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m'}, {'2021-09-06', '2021-09-05', '19:30 – 20:40\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n15:00 – 16:10\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m'}, {'9:30 – 10:40\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n11:00 – 12:10\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m', '2021-09-05', '2021-09-06'}, {'19:30 – 20:40\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n22:00 – 23:10\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m', '2021-09-05', '2021-09-06'}, {'2021-09-06', '2021-09-05', '7:00 – 8:10\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n13:40 – 14:50\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m'}]
    [{'13:10 – 20:03\nMIL Centrale\n‐\nROM Termini\n0 cambi\n6h 53m\n13:57 – 20:40\nROM Termini\n‐\nMIL Centrale\n0 cambi\n6h 43m', '2021-09-05', '2021-09-06'}, {'9:30 – 10:40\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n15:00 – 16:10\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m', '2021-09-05', '2021-09-06'}, {'15:00 – 16:10\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n13:40 – 14:50\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m', '2021-09-05', '2021-09-06'}, {'2021-09-06', '2021-09-05', '15:00 – 16:10\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n11:00 – 12:10\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m'}, {'2021-09-06', '2021-09-05', '19:30 – 20:40\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n15:00 – 16:10\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m'}, {'9:30 – 10:40\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n11:00 – 12:10\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m', '2021-09-05', '2021-09-06'}, {'19:30 – 20:40\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n22:00 – 23:10\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m', '2021-09-05', '2021-09-06'}, {'2021-09-06', '2021-09-05', '7:00 – 8:10\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n13:40 – 14:50\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m'}, {'15:00 – 16:10\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n17:30 – 18:40\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m', '2021-09-05', '2021-09-06'}]
    [{'13:10 – 20:03\nMIL Centrale\n‐\nROM Termini\n0 cambi\n6h 53m\n13:57 – 20:40\nROM Termini\n‐\nMIL Centrale\n0 cambi\n6h 43m', '2021-09-05', '2021-09-06'}, {'9:30 – 10:40\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n15:00 – 16:10\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m', '2021-09-05', '2021-09-06'}, {'15:00 – 16:10\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n13:40 – 14:50\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m', '2021-09-05', '2021-09-06'}, {'2021-09-06', '2021-09-05', '15:00 – 16:10\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n11:00 – 12:10\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m'}, {'2021-09-06', '2021-09-05', '19:30 – 20:40\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n15:00 – 16:10\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m'}, {'9:30 – 10:40\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n11:00 – 12:10\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m', '2021-09-05', '2021-09-06'}, {'19:30 – 20:40\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n22:00 – 23:10\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m', '2021-09-05', '2021-09-06'}, {'2021-09-06', '2021-09-05', '7:00 – 8:10\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n13:40 – 14:50\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m'}, {'15:00 – 16:10\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n17:30 – 18:40\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m', '2021-09-05', '2021-09-06'}, {'2021-09-05', '7:00 – 8:10\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n19:00 – 20:10\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m', '2021-09-06'}]
    [{'13:10 – 20:03\nMIL Centrale\n‐\nROM Termini\n0 cambi\n6h 53m\n13:57 – 20:40\nROM Termini\n‐\nMIL Centrale\n0 cambi\n6h 43m', '2021-09-05', '2021-09-06'}, {'9:30 – 10:40\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n15:00 – 16:10\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m', '2021-09-05', '2021-09-06'}, {'15:00 – 16:10\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n13:40 – 14:50\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m', '2021-09-05', '2021-09-06'}, {'2021-09-06', '2021-09-05', '15:00 – 16:10\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n11:00 – 12:10\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m'}, {'2021-09-06', '2021-09-05', '19:30 – 20:40\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n15:00 – 16:10\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m'}, {'9:30 – 10:40\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n11:00 – 12:10\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m', '2021-09-05', '2021-09-06'}, {'19:30 – 20:40\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n22:00 – 23:10\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m', '2021-09-05', '2021-09-06'}, {'2021-09-06', '2021-09-05', '7:00 – 8:10\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n13:40 – 14:50\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m'}, {'15:00 – 16:10\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n17:30 – 18:40\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m', '2021-09-05', '2021-09-06'}, {'2021-09-05', '7:00 – 8:10\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n19:00 – 20:10\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m', '2021-09-06'}, {'12:00 – 13:10\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n13:40 – 14:50\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m', '2021-09-05', '2021-09-06'}]
    [{'13:10 – 20:03\nMIL Centrale\n‐\nROM Termini\n0 cambi\n6h 53m\n13:57 – 20:40\nROM Termini\n‐\nMIL Centrale\n0 cambi\n6h 43m', '2021-09-05', '2021-09-06'}, {'9:30 – 10:40\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n15:00 – 16:10\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m', '2021-09-05', '2021-09-06'}, {'15:00 – 16:10\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n13:40 – 14:50\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m', '2021-09-05', '2021-09-06'}, {'2021-09-06', '2021-09-05', '15:00 – 16:10\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n11:00 – 12:10\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m'}, {'2021-09-06', '2021-09-05', '19:30 – 20:40\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n15:00 – 16:10\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m'}, {'9:30 – 10:40\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n11:00 – 12:10\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m', '2021-09-05', '2021-09-06'}, {'19:30 – 20:40\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n22:00 – 23:10\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m', '2021-09-05', '2021-09-06'}, {'2021-09-06', '2021-09-05', '7:00 – 8:10\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n13:40 – 14:50\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m'}, {'15:00 – 16:10\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n17:30 – 18:40\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m', '2021-09-05', '2021-09-06'}, {'2021-09-05', '7:00 – 8:10\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n19:00 – 20:10\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m', '2021-09-06'}, {'12:00 – 13:10\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n13:40 – 14:50\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m', '2021-09-05', '2021-09-06'}, {'2021-09-06', '2021-09-05', '7:00 – 8:10\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n17:30 – 18:40\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m'}]
    [{'13:10 – 20:03\nMIL Centrale\n‐\nROM Termini\n0 cambi\n6h 53m\n13:57 – 20:40\nROM Termini\n‐\nMIL Centrale\n0 cambi\n6h 43m', '2021-09-05', '2021-09-06'}, {'9:30 – 10:40\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n15:00 – 16:10\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m', '2021-09-05', '2021-09-06'}, {'15:00 – 16:10\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n13:40 – 14:50\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m', '2021-09-05', '2021-09-06'}, {'2021-09-06', '2021-09-05', '15:00 – 16:10\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n11:00 – 12:10\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m'}, {'2021-09-06', '2021-09-05', '19:30 – 20:40\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n15:00 – 16:10\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m'}, {'9:30 – 10:40\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n11:00 – 12:10\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m', '2021-09-05', '2021-09-06'}, {'19:30 – 20:40\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n22:00 – 23:10\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m', '2021-09-05', '2021-09-06'}, {'2021-09-06', '2021-09-05', '7:00 – 8:10\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n13:40 – 14:50\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m'}, {'15:00 – 16:10\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n17:30 – 18:40\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m', '2021-09-05', '2021-09-06'}, {'2021-09-05', '7:00 – 8:10\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n19:00 – 20:10\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m', '2021-09-06'}, {'12:00 – 13:10\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n13:40 – 14:50\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m', '2021-09-05', '2021-09-06'}, {'2021-09-06', '2021-09-05', '7:00 – 8:10\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n17:30 – 18:40\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m'}, {'12:00 – 13:10\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n15:00 – 16:10\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m', '2021-09-05', '2021-09-06'}]
    [{'13:10 – 20:03\nMIL Centrale\n‐\nROM Termini\n0 cambi\n6h 53m\n13:57 – 20:40\nROM Termini\n‐\nMIL Centrale\n0 cambi\n6h 43m', '2021-09-05', '2021-09-06'}, {'9:30 – 10:40\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n15:00 – 16:10\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m', '2021-09-05', '2021-09-06'}, {'15:00 – 16:10\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n13:40 – 14:50\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m', '2021-09-05', '2021-09-06'}, {'2021-09-06', '2021-09-05', '15:00 – 16:10\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n11:00 – 12:10\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m'}, {'2021-09-06', '2021-09-05', '19:30 – 20:40\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n15:00 – 16:10\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m'}, {'9:30 – 10:40\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n11:00 – 12:10\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m', '2021-09-05', '2021-09-06'}, {'19:30 – 20:40\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n22:00 – 23:10\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m', '2021-09-05', '2021-09-06'}, {'2021-09-06', '2021-09-05', '7:00 – 8:10\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n13:40 – 14:50\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m'}, {'15:00 – 16:10\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n17:30 – 18:40\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m', '2021-09-05', '2021-09-06'}, {'2021-09-05', '7:00 – 8:10\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n19:00 – 20:10\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m', '2021-09-06'}, {'12:00 – 13:10\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n13:40 – 14:50\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m', '2021-09-05', '2021-09-06'}, {'2021-09-06', '2021-09-05', '7:00 – 8:10\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n17:30 – 18:40\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m'}, {'12:00 – 13:10\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n15:00 – 16:10\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m', '2021-09-05', '2021-09-06'}, {'19:30 – 20:40\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n13:40 – 14:50\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m', '2021-09-05', '2021-09-06'}]
```

And when I try to print the detail_flights in a different cell of code I obtain this:

```
[{'13:10 – 20:03\nMIL Centrale\n‐\nROM Termini\n0 cambi\n6h 53m\n13:57 – 20:40\nROM Termini\n‐\nMIL Centrale\n0 cambi\n6h 43m', '2021-09-05', '2021-09-06'}, {'9:30 – 10:40\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n15:00 – 16:10\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m', '2021-09-05', '2021-09-06'}, {'15:00 – 16:10\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n13:40 – 14:50\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m', '2021-09-05', '2021-09-06'}, {'2021-09-06', '2021-09-05', '15:00 – 16:10\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n11:00 – 12:10\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m'}, {'2021-09-06', '2021-09-05', '19:30 – 20:40\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n15:00 – 16:10\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m'}, {'9:30 – 10:40\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n11:00 – 12:10\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m', '2021-09-05', '2021-09-06'}, {'19:30 – 20:40\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n22:00 – 23:10\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m', '2021-09-05', '2021-09-06'}, {'2021-09-06', '2021-09-05', '7:00 – 8:10\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n13:40 – 14:50\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m'}, {'15:00 – 16:10\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n17:30 – 18:40\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m', '2021-09-05', '2021-09-06'}, {'2021-09-05', '7:00 – 8:10\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n19:00 – 20:10\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m', '2021-09-06'}, {'12:00 – 13:10\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n13:40 – 14:50\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m', '2021-09-05', '2021-09-06'}, {'2021-09-06', '2021-09-05', '7:00 – 8:10\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n17:30 – 18:40\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m'}, {'12:00 – 13:10\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n15:00 – 16:10\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m', '2021-09-05', '2021-09-06'}, {'19:30 – 20:40\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\ndiretto\n1h 10m\n13:40 – 14:50\nFCO Roma-Fiumicino\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 10m', '2021-09-05', '2021-09-06'}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the data from all the links, all your code has to be inside the for loop:

```
for link in list_link:
  wd.get(link)
  ....
```

This part of your code:

```
j = 0
lngth = len(wd.find_elements_by_css_selector(".mainInfo"))
....
```

is only using the last link.

Also, I advise you to use **webdriver_manager** and forget about handling chromedriver files forever.

This is an edited version of your code (a little bit simplified), that uses **webdriver_manager**:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pprint
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

list_link = ['https://www.kayak.it/flights/MIL-BCN/2021-09-05/2021-09-06/?sort=bestflight__a&fs=stops=0',
             'https://www.kayak.it/flights/MIL-PAR/2021-09-05/2021-09-06/?sort=bestflight__a&fs=stops=0',
             'https://www.kayak.it/flights/MIL-ROM/2021-09-05/2021-09-06/?sort=bestflight__a&fs=stops=0']

wd = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
wd.maximize_window()
wd.implicitly_wait(5)
wait = WebDriverWait(wd, 5)

detail_flights = []

for link in list_link:
    wd.get(link)
    try:
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[title='Accetta']"))).click()
    except:
        pass

    try:
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[id='onetrust-accept-btn-handler']"))).click()
    except:
        pass
    try:
        if len(wd.find_elements_by_css_selector(".mainInfo")) > 0:
            elements = wd.find_elements_by_css_selector(".mainInfo")
            for element in elements:
                wd.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element)
                date = link.replace('https://www.kayak.it/flights/', '')
                data_partenza = date[8:18]
                data_ritorno = date[19:29]
                detail_flights.append({element.get_attribute('innerText'), data_partenza, data_ritorno})
        else:
            print('Nothing more to scrape')
    except:
        pass

for flight in detail_flights:
    print(flight)
```